# sizeof(struct) returns a SMALLER than expected value?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

I have this c++ structure:

```
struct Packet
{
    uint32 MessageCount; 
    uint32 Length; 
    uint32 FieldValue;

    union PacketHeader
    {
        uint32 typeInfo; 
        struct MagicVersion
        {
            uint8 MagicNumber[3];
            uint8 Version; 
        };
     };

    Data * Payload(void) { return reinterpret_cast< Data * >(this + 1U); }
    Data const * Payload(void) const { return reinterpret_cast< Data const * >(this + 1U); }

    Packet * nextPacket(void) { return reinterpret_cast< Packet * >(this + 1U) + Length; }
    Packet const * nextPacket(void) const { return reinterpret_cast< Packet const * >(this + 1U) + Length; }
};
```

Then `sizeof(Packet)` in MSVC++ returns 12 instead of 16 which is what I expect.

The weird thing is of course that this is smaller that the expected value. Had it been bigger it could be because of alignment issues.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Note that you should not use this union to convert between uint32_t and uint8_t[]; that's UB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you think it should be bigger?

It contains 3 `uint32` with no virtual methods, that's exactly 12 bytes.

The union doesn't count, since it's a type, it contains no member of that type.

If you want your class to contain a single instance of the union, which contains a single instance of the struct, you should write:

```
struct Packet
{
    uint32 MessageCount; 
    uint32 Length; 
    uint32 FieldValue;

    union
    {
        uint32 typeInfo; 
        struct
        {
            uint8 MagicNumber[3];
            uint8 Version; 
        } /* MagicVersion */;
     };
} /* PacketHeader */;
```

The names within `/**/` are optional, you can either specify them or not. If you do, you have to access their members using the name of the `union`/`struct`, otherwise you'll have a flat `Packet` struct.

Comment: C++, however, does support both unnamed and anonymous unions. So if he removes PacketHeader that should work.

Comment: It does. If you remove the `PacketHeader` name after the `union` keyword, `sizeof(Packet)` will be 16 bytes.

Comment: but g++ would then whine, because the named struct nested in a nameless union cannot exist.

Comment: because that again has the name at the wrong location. If you want to declare a single instance of an anonymous struct, you should put the name after the closing bracket. Or you could do it without providing a name for it.